# How is the prediction variance defined?

Tags: time-series

I wonder how the output `$var.pred` returned by `ar.ols()` in R is defined?
It is not the variance of a prediction value, is it? I guess no, because the variances of $n$-step ahead forecasts may be different for different $n$, correct?

Does it equal the covariance matrix of the forecast error?

Does it equal the residual covariance matrix?

From `?ar.ols()`

```
var.pred: The prediction variance: an estimate of the portion of the
          variance of the time series that is not explained by the
          autoregressive model.
```

Following is an example (`x` is a bivariate time series):

```
> output = ar.ols(x, aic = F, order.max = 2, demean = F, intercept = T)
> output

Call:
ar.ols(x = x, aic = F, order.max = 2, demean = F, intercept = T)

$ar
, , 1

        TS1    TS2
TS1  0.5592 0.3561
TS2 -0.1555 0.1147

, , 2

        TS1    TS2
TS1 -0.3455 0.5119
TS2  0.2105 0.4648


$x.intercept
  TS1   TS2 
2.195 3.891 

$var.pred
      TS1    TS2
TS1 1.583  1.582
TS2 1.582 18.446t
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

it appears to be the variance of AR innovations, i.e. 1-step ahead prediction error

That is, if

$X_t = AX_{t-1} + E_{t}$

then it's the variance matrix of $E$.

Comment: Thanks. In the example, my AR model has order 2 instead of 1. Is the prediction variance still equal to the  1-step ahead prediction error

Comment: yes the AR order does not matter